# How to change tooltip's background color in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, personalization, tooltip

How do I change tooltip's background color on Ubuntu desktop "Xfce". I know how to change in Gnome but I can't find out how to do so in Xfce.

Tooltip's background color in Eclipse is black, and font's color is black too.

Answer (score 5):

To do it manually:

- If you want to change the tooltip settings for all GTK2 apps, then edit `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.
- Or, If you just want to change settings for Eclipse, then edit `~/gtkrc-eclipse` and then start eclipse with `GTK2_RC_FILES=~/gtkrc-eclipse eclipse`):

Add the following to your `gtkrc` file.

```
style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
```

Alternatively, you can do this from a GUI:

- Install [gnome-color-chooser [image: Install gnome-color-chooser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-color-chooser).
- Go to *Specific* tab > *Tooltips* and check *Foreground (black)* and *Background (yellow)*. Click apply.
- The settings are saved to `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and `~/.gtkrc-2.0-gnome-color-chooser`.

Comment: The GUI way works perfectly for me. Now I have readable tooltips in Firefox, again. Thanks.

Comment: The GUI way worked well for our team also - much easier than mucking around with config files.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here: [ubuntuforums.org - Tooltips/Info popup color scheme change](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=438435) for default 11.04 Xubuntu swap references to clearlooks with greybird. Good luck.

*Excerpt from the thead:*

> So, to sum it all up, for happy yellow tooltips (In Xubuntu)
>
> Open a terminal, type stuff in:
>
> ```
> gksudo mousepad /usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
> ```
>
> Paste the following at the end of the file:
>
> ```
> style "clearlooks-tooltips" = "clearlooks-default"
> {
>         xthickness = 4
>         ythickness = 4
>         bg[NORMAL] = { 1.0,1.0,0.75 }
> }
>
> widget "gtk-tooltips" style "clearlooks-tooltips"
> ```
>
> Switch to a different theme, than back again. Yellow tooltips.
>   Yay!
>
> The same thing will work for normal Ubuntu, just swap mousepad out
>   for gedit in the terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified `gtkrc` in my radiance theme to correct the color issue on tooltips in Eclipse.

In order to modify in your system, run:

- To open with Terminal based text editor:

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
  ```
- To open with GUI based text editor (`leafpad`):

  ```
  gksudo leafpad /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
  ```

**NOTE: Make sure you back up the above file before you make changes.**

You need to make the following two changes to correct the tooltip issue:

1. Replace the first line with

   ```
   gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#000000\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#f6f4f2\ntooltip_bg_color:#FFFFE1\nlink_color:#DD4814"
   ```
2. Search for

   ```
   bg[SELECTED]      = "#000000"
   ```

   and replace the line with

   ```
   bg[SELECTED]      = "#ffffff"
   ```

Save the changes and restart Eclipse after that to see the changes.

Comment: Colors can be changed on per user basis by editing ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and ~/.config/gtk-2.0/settings.ini

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem (mostly in Eclipse). Changing the theme was not an option, because I like Greybird. I found a [solution at this blog](http://www.rohmatic.com/notebook/changing-tooltip-colors-in-xubuntu-themes/).

> To start you will need to edit these three files:
>
> - /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
> - /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
> - /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
>
> You will need to look for the following entries and replace their values:
>
> ```
> tooltip_bg_color
> tooltip_fg_color
> ```
>
> For my tastes, I’ve used `#EAEAEA` as the tooltip background color and `#666666` for the tooltip foreground color (the font color). That’s it!